# После оформление заказа выходит JSON код?

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста у меня после оформление заказа когда нажимаю на кнопку ОФОРМИТЬ ЗАКАЗ, выходит какие то надписи JSON кода, хотя должно выходит надпись "Ваш заказ успешно оформлен на сайте" (Это выходит в обычном состояний браузера, без инкогнито). Самое интересное что данные загружаются в заказах, и когда я оформляю через режим инкогнито все исправно работает. Купили шаблон aspro next, и установили.

Может у вас было такая похожая проблема, мне кажется это связано с Битрикс а не шаблоном, до этого в старых версиях Битрикс тоже выводилось, только сейчас не помню как решил. Смотрел настройки компонента sale.order.ajax, без результата.
Даже не знаю какую сторону копать, написал в тех поддержку пока жду.

1) Использую предпоследнюю версию sale.order.ajax - который работает на PHP.

2) Код который выводится прикреплю с screenshot - ом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Новая версия Битрикс

Искал в интернете, встретил только одна статейку, и то не было ответа.

Comment: Добрый день. Смотрите файл, который формирует эту страницу и ищите вывод json строки. Возможно это кто-то сделал до Вас для тестирования.

Comment: Здравствуйте. У меня появились несколько вопросов, буду благодарен если Вы ответите на них. Получается это код json в конце выводится чисто для проверки? В каком файле мне лучше смотреть в компоненте sale.order.ajax - template.php или confirm.php. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Доброе утро. Смотрите во всех файлах, которые отвечают за оформление заказа.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку, нашел в коде sale.order.ajax - template.php

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет. Нашел ответ на свой вопрос - данный компонент я скачал из сайта camouf предпоследняя версия компонента sale.order.ajax - работает на php. Данная код выводился из за

```
 <input type="hidden" name="json" value="Y">
```

в файле template.php формы. Закоментил код и все стало на свои места. Может кому то поможет данное решение.